# Microsoft Bot Framework - Email channel - Unable to save email

Tags: botframework

The Microsoft bot framework channel "Email" is not working. I tried to add different emails including Office 365, @outlook.com , @gmail.com, none of them working, The screen showing an error status "Unable to save email".

It seems this was working earlier. My email is accessible via email/password and office 365 enabled , but from bot framework email channel - its returning an error "Unable to save email". Could anyone please help on this.

Comment: @outlook.com email addresses do work in the bot framework email channel (I've got a couple bots that are using @outlook.com). Please try again.  It might be a temporary issue.

Comment: my personal email outlook.com and another outlook.com email is not working . I am from india and not sure whether region wise restrictions exists or not. Another possibility is my username has a dot character, just a guess whether that causing an issue. Let's see whether its a temporary issue, will try after 2 days and update it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email channel can only be used with `Office 365 accounts` as described in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-email?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365):

> The Email channel currently works with Office 365 only. Other email
> services are not currently supported.

So it will not work with `@gmail.com` accounts.

I checked again 2 minutes ago and from my side I also have the problem of getting `Unable to save` error during registration of the email (with an email that was previously working).

When having a look to the console of my navigator, I see that there is an internal server error (error 500) for `POST https://dev.botframework.com/api/bots/myBotName/channels/email`

=> I will log an issue on Github Bot framework's project

Comment: @outlook.com email addresses do in fact work in the Microsoft Bot Framework's Email channel.  Please try emailing getweather@outlook.com with a body asking for the weather in a city: "What is the weather in Miami, FL?"

Comment: @EricDahlvang good to know, new feature? A few weeks ago I remember reading that only Office 365 was allowed. I'm removing outlook.com from my answer

Comment: thanks for all your work on the forums.  You are super helpful!